# Some questions in **Modulational stability of ground states of nonlinear Schrödinger equations**

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stability-theory, parabolic-pde

Pictures below is from
*Weinstein, Michael I.*, [**Modulational stability of ground states of nonlinear Schrödinger equations**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0516034), SIAM J. Math. Anal. 16, 472-491 (1985). [ZBL0583.35028](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0583.35028).

For $0<\sigma<\frac{2}{N-2}$ ($N$ is the dimension of space),
$$
L_- = -\Delta +1 -R^{2\sigma}  
$$
where $R$ is the solution of
$$
\Delta u -u + |u|^{2\sigma}u=0\tag{1.4}
$$
First, I don't know what is ground state. Seemly, the ground state is the solution of (1.4) with minimal $L^2$ norm. Whether it is right ?

About $R$,  we have the properties in first picture below. But why in second picture below, $L_-$ is nonnegative ? In my view, nonnegative means that
$$
(L_-v,v)\ge 0
$$
I can't get it from the fact that $R$ is ground.

Besides, what is the mean of ground state is nondegenerate ?   I don't know what is nondegenerate. Seemly, in other paper, the nondegerate is the kernel of operator is the partial derivative of solution. But here, I don't whether it is.

---

---

> > [image]

---

---

> > [image]
> > [image]

Comment: You can read more about the ground state in Tao's book "Nonlinear Dispersive Equations", in particular Ch. B. The ground state shows that solutions of the focusing NLS don't need to disperse. Nondegenerate refers to uniqueness, e.g. the first eigenvalue is non-degenerate if it is unique up to a multiplicative constant. For any symmetric linear operator $A$, if $0$ is the first eigenvalue, then $(Au,u)\ge 0$ for every $u$.

Comment: @user90189  Thanks,  although I have know what is ground state, but the book you recommending is very interesting.